# jQuery cart functions have some slight issues

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/99efL4xz/2/

Partial JS:

```
function addToBasket(title, sku, price, image, qty) {
  // update sku if product is already present
  $.each(basket, function (product) {
    if (basket[product].sku === sku) {
      basket[product].sku = sku;  // replace existing Qty
      saveBasket();

      return;
    }
  });

  // create object
  var item = { title: title, sku: sku, price: price, image: image, qty: qty }; 
  basket.push(item);
  saveBasket();
}
```

Issues:

- When I add to cart, it works fine... if i add another it adds as a new item rather than updating the cart item by SKU and increasing the QTY
- It updates the cart amount and price in the cart but when you add another its not changing... I'm struggling with updating this and working it out.

Comment: `product` is an object, not an index. Just do `if (product.sku === sku)`. Also, there's no point in assigning `product.sku` to `sku` since you already established they're the same in your if condition.

Comment: @MikeC: I think in jQuery the first param is an index.

Comment: @squint Dang it, you're right. It's backwards from everything else. Okay, well, the bit about re-assigning `sku` still stands.

Comment: You're right, it seems he's just updating the wrong property.

Comment: well funny you say that, that is how i had it before as assumed that would be the case but was still adding to basket as a new object... but let me change back to that and double check lol

Comment: Yep still adds as a new object, as if i refresh it shows twice in the mini cart... i updated here for you to see: https://jsfiddle.net/99efL4xz/3/

Comment: ...also it seems that you're expecting the `return` statement to exit the `addToBasket` function. That won't happen. You're just returning from the callback.

Comment: Ive done this with trial and error, just touching JS and stuff.... think im doing ok so far though but just stuck at this point now lol

Comment: Since `basket` is an array, I would use the newer ES6 methods, like `.find()`. They can be easily patched. So then it's just `var product = basket.find(function(prod) { return prod.sku === sku }); if (product) { ...update the product... } else { ...push in the new product...} saveBasket();`

Comment: Let me see if i can work that out with your suggestion, thanks for your help btw.... ill give it a go now! :)

Comment: I tried this but did not work... guess i got it wrong? function addToBasket(title, sku, price, image, qty) {
  // update sku if product is already present
  $.each(basket, function (product) {
    var product = basket.find(function(prod) { 
      return prod.sku === sku
    }); 
    if (product) { 
      product.sku = sku;  // replace existing Qty
    } else { 
      // create object
      var item = { title: title, sku: sku, price: price, image: image, qty: qty }; 
      basket.push(item);
    } 
    saveBasket();
  });
}

Comment: @James: I meant ditching `$.each` and using `.find()` instead. I'll post an answer so it's clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@MikeC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c) pointed out, you were finding the object by the `sku` but then assigning the matching `sku` to that property, which resulted in no actual change.

It seems that you wanted to update `qty` instead.

Also, your `return` statement is inside the `$.each` callback, so it isn't going to prevent the code below the `$.each` from running.

ECMAScript 6 offers a number of new Array methods, one of which is [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). I'd suggest using that to locate the object in the Array, and then update it if it was found, or push a new item if not.

```
function addToBasket(title, sku, price, image, qty) {
  // update sku if product is already present
  var product = basket.find(function (prod) {
    return prod.sku === sku
  })

  if (product) { // found an object, so update it with the new quantity
    product.qty = qty

  } else { // no object found, so create a new object
    basket.push({ title: title, sku: sku, price: price, image: image, qty: qty });
  }

  saveBasket();
}
```

The return value of the callback to [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) determines whether or not the current item in the array is the one you want. Returning `true` (or any truthy value) makes the iteration stop, and gives you that object. If no item returned a truthy value, `undefined` is returned.

So then after the loop, if an object was found, you update it, and if not, you make a new one.

---

You'll need to patch [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) into older browsers. There's a polyfill in the MDN docs I linked.

Comment: Thanks for the help in advance! I just gave that a go... it update price and amount in the bubble as expected... i refresh to see the minicart and it show but when i then add to basket again does not work and i see in console: prod is not defined - any ideas? thanks again mate!

Comment: @James: `prod` is only available inside the callback. If that's where the error is, then maybe you have some empty (null/undefined) items in the `basket`. ...try `return prod && prod.sku === sku`

Comment: Ive not used prod before, everything in the array is product and then like product.image, product.sku, product.price, product.qty etc...

Comment: ...sorry, it's a mistake in my answer. `prod.qty = qty` should be `product.qty = qty`

Comment: Yea thought it was hehe i just done if (product) { // found an object, so update it with the new quantity
    product.qty = qty;
    console.log(basket);
  } so i could see console basket in log but always stays as 1 and does not update... any ideas? sorry to be a pain and thanks for all your help.

Comment: @James: It should be assigning whatever quantity you pass it. So if you're still passing `1`, then it will assign that. Log your values to the console to debug the issue.

Comment: In the HTML link i have data-qty="1" - so maybe that is why? I assume would need to check the basket session and if exists to get that value and add to it? and then save?

Comment: Sorry i assumed thats what it was doing anyway or am i wrong? sorry... all learning curve for me lol

Comment: I don't know how the app is meant to work, but if the quantity passed will always be `1`, then maybe you just need to use addition in `addToBasket`... `product.qty += qty` I can't stick around right now. Best of luck!